# Azure Pipeline - validate if previous step / script failed or succeeded

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

We are trying to validate if the previous script in a deployment went through successfully.
I know about conditions and am trying to add a condition that validates if the previous script failed or succeeded.

As seen in the example below, there exists a parameter called name.
[Sample screenshot from the script documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKv2j.png)
From the documentation, this parameter is used as ID for the script.
I can not find the documentation on how to properly address this id and then utilize it in a condition to reach the below specified output.
The whole behavior should be implemented utilizing yaml pipelines only.

There may or may not be steps between script1 and script2

I specifically want to do this step on the script level, not on a job/stage level.

Expected behavior (pseudocode):

```
if script1 succeeds:
  skip script2
else:
  execute script2
```

Some sample of what I am trying / have tried to achieve:

```
- script1: "some script"
  name: script1

<... potentially other scripts ...>

- script2: "some more script"
  condition: eq(script1, 'Failed')
```